# How can I set up ui-less external API auth using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, authentication, jwt, authorization

I'm trying to create an external API using *AWS API Gateway* that will give users access to data stored in multiple databases. The APIs will mostly be accessed through scripts rather than through a web UI.

Are there any AWS services I can use to manage user access to my API?

I've read a little bit about *Amazon Cognito* and *OAuth 2* but at a glance it seems like those might be more targeted towards cases with a UI for users to interact with. Is there a way to create and manage API keys with AWS?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [API Gateway Lambda Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) to write your custom login integration. For example a lambda that check in one Database if the user:password (passed as authorization header) exists in table in DynamoDB or SQL.